# Questions regarding pdf to image conversion with Node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf, file-conversion, pdf-conversion

The plan is to create a pdf file (that only consists of a single page) then the user chooses whether to download as PDF or image. I have already written the code for generating the PDF and it is working fine as of now. The problem now is how to convert this to image. Is it possible to convert files without installing stuff like Ghostscript etc?

I am a complete noob, advice is greatly appreciated. (Recommendations on which libraries to use would also be helpful)

**Code for generating the PDF**

```
  import PDFDocument from "pdfkit";

  static async medicalPrescription(req, res) {
    // Some code for generating the PDF contents...


    filename = encodeURIComponent(filename) + '.pdf'
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"')
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')
    const content = req.body.content
    doc.y = 300
    doc.text(content, 50, 50)
    doc.pipe(res)
    doc.end()
  }
```

The client then receives the generated file and opens it in another tab.

**React file that sends the request and opens the response**

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    // Some code for sending the pdf content from the user

    fetch("http://localhost:5050/generate-rx", { 
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: parsed
    })

      .then(async res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          const blob = await res.blob();
          const file = new Blob(
            [blob], 
            {type: 'application/pdf'}
          );
          const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          window.open(fileURL);  
        }
      }) 
  }
```

Comment: "Is it possible to convert files without installing stuff like Ghostscript etc?" What's wrong with Ghostscript? What's wrong with "installing stuff"?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pdf2pic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2pic). It can convert pdf to image.

```
import { fromPath } from "pdf2pic";

const options = {
  density: 100,
  saveFilename: "untitled",
  savePath: "./images",
  format: "png",
  width: 600,
  height: 600
};
const storeAsImage = fromPath("/path/to/pdf/sample.pdf", options);
const pageToConvertAsImage = 1;

storeAsImage(pageToConvertAsImage).then((resolve) => {
  console.log("Page 1 is now converted as image");

 console.log(resolve); // send resolve to user
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `pdf.js` [1] and `node-canvas`[3] library

Installation

```
npm install pdfjs-dist canvas
```

Usage

```js
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';
import * as PDFJSWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker';
import { createCanvas, loadImage } from 'canvas';


// Function to convert BinaryData to an image and return the base64 representation
export const convertBinaryDataToBase64Image = async (binaryData) => {
  pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = PDFJSWorker;
  try {
    // Initialize PDF.js with the BinaryData
    const pdfDoc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: binaryData }).promise;

    // Get the first page of the PDF
    const page = await pdfDoc.getPage(1);

    // Get the dimensions and scale of the PDF page
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });

    // Create a canvas and rendering context
    const canvas = createCanvas(viewport.width, viewport.height)
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Render the PDF page as an image on the canvas
    await page.render({ canvasContext: context, viewport }).promise;

    // Convert the canvas content to a data URL (base64)
    const imageDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); // Change 'image/png' to the desired format if needed

    return imageDataURL;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during the conversion
    throw new Error(`Error converting PDF to image: ${error}`);
  }
};
```

The above function returns a `base64` string of the converted pdf to image. The function accepts a BinaryData or ArrayBuffer. If you're using `axios` and your response returns a pdf blob, it's just a matter of adding `responseType: 'arraybuffer'`[2] to your request config.

Do note that I'm justing printing the 1st page, because my pdf is only one page. Adapt it based on your pdf.

Writing the base64 to disk is easy enough

```js
let buff = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
fs.writeFileSync('image-name.png', buff);
```

### Resources

1. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js
2. [https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config#:~:text=browser%20only%3A%20%27blob%27-,responseType,-%3A%20%27json%27](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config#:%7E:text=browser%20only%3A%20%27blob%27-,responseType,-%3A%20%27json%27)
3. https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

Comment: The question is about NodeJS, not the browser environment. `document.createElement()` is not available in NodeJS.

Comment: @JeffMcMahan Have updated with node. Thanks!

Comment: @BaidalSaibo No you didn't. `document.createElement()` will not be available in node unless you use a headless browser - and your code doesn't.

Comment: @JeffMcMahan Updated with node-canvas. Thanks again :)

Comment: @BadalSaibo can it work with node V14 ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to convert `pdf` to `image` without installing stuff like Ghostscript, `pdf.js` + `canvas` can do this.

It is a good option when your hosting/environment doesn't allow to install additional `apt` packages like Ghostscript.

Here is a link to [node-example](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/pdf2png/pdf2png.js) of `pdf.js` usage to convert pdf to png

- Code from this example worked for me with `pdfjs-dist@2.16.105` and
  latest `canvas@2.11.2`.
- Also pay attention that to use `pdf.js` at
  nodejs you need to use legacy build:
  `require("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js")`