# how to convert pdf to image using npm package

Tags: node.js, image, pdf, file-upload, imagemagick

uploads/1664344016499.pdf
Error: Command failed: magick convert uploads/1664344016499.pdf -quality 100 output-%3d.jpg
/bin/sh: 1: magick: not found

```
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:446:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:686:12) {
```

killed: false,
code: 127,
signal: null,
cmd: 'magick convert uploads/1664344016499.pdf -quality 100 output-%3d.jpg'

Comment: Please suggest any documentation or videos

Comment: check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/69520876/11395491

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.